# Creating Map from database

Tags: qgis, python, geoserver, real-time, geoalchemy

I'd like some general advice on creating dynamic maps. I have a bunch of geospatial points saved on SQL Server and PostgreSQL. People will enter new data into the databases from time to time. I want those points to be automatically plotted into a series of base layers I have already created with QGIS. The plotting does not have to be instantaneous, but it would be nice if the map was updated every day. I've got a few `leaflet` maps that I especially like, but I'm not tied to them. I have a decent bit of SQL, some python, marginal amounts of HTML and PHP experience, and practically no JavaScript. To be perfectly honest, I don't know where to start in figuring out how to this. I have very little as far as budget is concerned, but lots of free time to learn how to program better. I have been doing some research and I'm still pretty confused on where to start. I was wondering if anyone had a good resource on where to get started.

Right now, I am thinking the best thing for me to do would be learning `geoalchemy2` on python to create the type of map I want to create. I'm pretty sure `geoalchemy2` can do this, but could anyone confirm?

Comment: do you just want one static map that you convert to an image?  or do you want to have some sort of zoom/pan map on a website?  or is it not web-based and you just want a shape file?

Comment: I'd prefer to have some sort of zoom-pan. Thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created the layers in QGIS and you want to publish them using the same style, I think you should go with [QGIS Web Client](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client).

Related to the new points, everytime the user load the WebGIS application, a new request will be made to the database and so the information will be always updated.